# Generate OpenCV 64-bit DLL

Tags: c++, opencv, c++-cli

I sucessfully compiled a 32-bit DLL using c++/cli/OpenCV in Viusal Studio 2010.
I am trying to create a 64-bit DLL. When I change the Build configuration to x64 and compile it, it gives me

```
c:\opencv2.2\include\opencv2\core\mat.hpp(379): fatal error C1001: An internal error has   
occurred in the compiler. (compiler file     \
'f:\dd\vctools\compiler\utc\src\p2\wvm\mdmiscw.c', line 2704)
```

Any tips?

UPDATE:
It turned out that c++-cli has some bug with opencv 64 bit. I added this

```
   #pragma managed(push, off)
   #include <opencv/cv.h> 
   #pragma managed(pop)
```

and that fixed it

Comment: The only thing you can do with an ICE is [submit a bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/).

Comment: I'd be curious to see what mat.hpp line 379 contained, even though it's not your code.

Comment: That's line 379
 

 inline void Mat::release()
{
    if( refcount && CV_XADD(refcount, -1) == 1 )
        deallocate();
    data = datastart = dataend = datalimit = 0;
    size.p[0] = 0;
    refcount = 0;
}

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to be sure to enclose your `#include` statements in `#pragma managed(off)`, but since it compiled as 32-bit, that's probably not it.

Comment: opencv 2.2 is a very very old version. There might have been a lot of code that was written with assumption that may not be valid for 64 bit compilation. Did you consider moving to the latest version? 2.4 or greater?

Comment: I installed opencv 2.4 and i included the x64 lib but still the same problem 
c:\opencv2.4\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.hpp(362): fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
1>  (compiler file 'f:\dd\vctools\compiler\utc\src\p2\wvm\mdmiscw.c', line 2704)

Comment: It turned out that c++-cli has some bug with opencv 64 bit. 
I added this
#pragma managed(push, off)
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#pragma managed(pop)

and that fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that c++-cli has some bug with opencv 64 bit. I added this

```
   #pragma managed(push, off)
   #include <opencv/cv.h> 
   #pragma managed(pop)
```